# Dynamic forecasting the data.table way?

Tags: r, data.table, forecasting, shift, predict

I need to create dynamic forecast using

```
v(t) = b0 + b1*v(t-1) + b2*v(t-2) + b3*x(t-1) + b4*x(t-2)
```

The dataset looks like this at time 0. In actual data, there are 80 different x's and 100K "dates".

```
date           v   vLag1   vLag2   x    xLag1   xLag2   b1    b2   b3    b4 
2016-06-30    NA   105     95      33   11      23      0.2   3.2  -1.2  0.4
2016-07-01    NA   NA      NA      43   33      11      0.2   3.2  -1.2  0.4
2016-07-02    NA   NA      NA      52   43      33      0.2   3.2  -1.2  0.4
```

The goal is to predict **v**'s, replacing all NA's with values. I created **vLag1, vLag2, xLag1, xLag2** so that I have all I need to calculate **v**  in one row.

All **x**'s and **b**'s are known ahead of time, so I created lags of **x** shown above. The **b**'s are the coefficients.

For each date, the **v(t)** would be predicted, and the predicted **v(t)**'s will feed into the next date's **v** prediction as the lagged regressors.

To avoid looping over rows like this:

```
for (i in 2:nrows){
  df$v[i] <- df$v[i-1] * df$coeff[i]
}
```

I have tried to use repeated substitution, so that all the future **v**'s only reference **v1**, which is easy to calculate because **v1**'s calculation involves other values in the same row.

```
 v2 = b0 + b1*v1 + b2*v0 + b3*x1 + b4*x0
 v3 = b0 + b1*v2 + b2*v1 + b3*x2 + b4*x1 
 (substitute v2) v3 = b0 + b1*(b0 + b1*v1 + b2*v0 + b3*x1 + b4*x0) + b2*v1 + b3*x2 + b4*x1 
 v4 = ...
```

But with so many lags of **v**'s and **x**'s to keep track, this also got out of control.

I have been browsing the **data.table**'s **shift** function in SO. But, in my case, where the the values need to be dynamically obtained and then shifted, is there any way to dynamically predict in **data.table**'s functions?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of data.table (where you can't do this easily) this looks like an easy job for Rcpp:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;    

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector dyn_fore(const NumericVector x,
                       const double v1, const double v2, 
                       const double x1, const double x2, 
                       const double b0, const double b1, const double b2, 
                       const double b3, const double b4) {
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector v(n);
  v(0) = b0 + b1*v1 + b2*v2 + b3*x1 + b4*x2;
  v(1) = b0 + b1*v(0) + b2*v1 + b3*x(0) + b4*x1; 
  for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    v(i) = b0 + b1*v(i-1) + b2*v(i-2) + b3*x(i-1) + b4*(i-2);
  }
  return v;
}
```

(If you use Windows, make sure you have a working Rtools installation, put this in an C++ File in RStudio and source it. Check if I got coefficients and indices right.)

Then in R:

```
x <- c(33, 43, 52, 67)
dyn_fore(x, 105, 95, 11, 23, 0, 0.2, 3.2, -1.2, 0.4)
#[1]  321.00  365.00 1048.60 1315.72
```

Comment: I actually began looking into the Rcpp way, and running into trouble with ENV PATH causing the g++ compiler not belng found. Once I resolve it, I will try your solution.

Comment: Follow the available instructions on setting up your system and it should work without a problem. Rcpp is very useful for tasks for which loops are very natural but not sufficiently efficient in R.